# Is there any way to remove / ignore raid controller

Tags: windows-7, raid

I have a server with 2 mirrored drives.  With Server 2003 os.  I want to install Windows 7 on the box and remove the raid configuration.  Only reason I want to remove the Raid config is that I can't find the Raid controller drivers (or the drivers I have found dont seem to work) for Win 7 install.  I'm quite happy not bothering with the mirrored drives.  I've gone into the Raid menu and set both disks to be non-raid and I can see in the Raid Disk Drive list that there is now nothing there.

But, when I try Win 7 installation dvd I still get a Load Drivers popup.  If I click on repair I have no hard drives in the disk selection box.  So I am assuming its still something to do with the raid existing??

I know the disks are fine because if i dont run the dvd I can boot up into Server 2003 with no problems and see both of the disks.  The Raid controller is a JMicron controller by the way on an ABIT AB9 motherboard.  I don't understand why the install needs the drivers if there are no Raid drives.  Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the disks without the RAID you will need to unhook them from the RAID controller and connect them to the built in SATA/IDE ports on the motherboard. Otherwise you will need to load the RAID drivers so Windows knows how to talk to the RAID controller which is sitting between your drives and the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

If the OS does not recognize the storage controller in general, its going to ask for drivers. I'm assuming you only broke the mirror set, so there is still an install of Server 2003? Drivers are [here](http://www.abit.com.tw/page/uk/download/download_driver_detail.php?pFILE_TYPE=Driver&pMAIN_TYPE=Motherboard&pTITLE_ON_SCREEN=AB9&pSOCKET_TYPE=LGA775) and you will will probably just want the JMicron SATA one, but you should also grab the RAID ones as well to be safe. Even though they aren't in a RAID configuration, they are still connected to the controller. There isn't one for Win7, but you could experiment with the Vista one.

Comment: I changed the Sata ports of the Drives to ones that aren't connected to the Raid controller.  It's hard to tell because the Raid controller is integrated on the motherboard.  But, I still get the Driver popup during install and none of the drivers seem to work.  Yes, both drives still have an install of server 2003 and boot up fine.

Comment: But did you download the drivers and have them on a floppy for the OS to use? That's why I suggested downloading both.